# DB2 - subquery with multiple rows, returning as correlated row

Tags: sql, db2

I would like to return a small subset of data WITH the larger data set... it really ONLY has to be a string upon returning - because it's simply going to be displayed... IS THIS POSSIBLE?

my scenario - lets say I have a list of people, and I want to return that list - BUT include a blurb of information that they made 'entries' on three previous dates...

I COULD, loop over the main set, and re-query the db for the last three date that the current user made 'entries'  - but this would result in LOTS of extra call to the db - terribly inefficient.

I COULD simply join the information, and GROUP on my output, (and I have no proof) but I think this is kinda wasteful too, as I'm relying on a loop in a loop for my output.

I THINK I would like to return these "last three" entry dates as a simple string in a sub query... so that the data set would simply contain a 'string' representation of the data I want... therefore my Loop output would be VERY efficient...as would my query to the DB...

Here's what I have sofar - but it bombs, and I can find out why...

```
SELECT 
        U.intID,
        U.strName,
       (
            SELECT TRIM(CAST(CAST(EO.intData AS CHAR(25)) AS VARCHAR(25))) || ' on ' || TRIM(CAST(EO.dateRecorded AS VARCHAR(25))) || '<br/>'
            FROM   metrics EO
            WHERE  EO.fkID = U.intID
            ORDER BY EO.dateRecorded DESC
            FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
        ) AS strLast3
    FROM live.tblUsers U
```

Comment: You should check whether anyone's given workable answers to any of your other questions; if they have *in your judgement*, marking them “the answer” (by clicking on the check mark next to them) will help others understand what a good solution is. It also rewards the answerers through the reputation system, and encourages people (who like to play rep like a game) to provide more answers.

Comment: (And no, I know I don't know the answer to this one. I'm a total novice when it comes to advanced SQL queries.)

Comment: what version DB2 are you using and on what platform?

Answer (score 0):

I use a UDF() for that type of thing. Basically you write an SQL function that takes the intID as parameter. The function would then look up the metrics for that id and return them all in a string. In this way you keep the fugly string manipulations out of the way and can do something like this in you main code:

```
SELECT U.intID, 
       U.strName, 
       GetMetrics( U.intID )
FROM live.tblUsers U
```